# Setting the angle of a turtle in Python

Tags: python, angle, turtle-graphics

I'm creating a function that will cause a giraffe to move in a certain direction and distance (don't ask).

If the user types "west" in the parameters, the turtle should move west however the direction is. But the turtle's angle changes every time, I can't fix a value for my turtle to turn to go a certain direction.

I need to set the angle to, say, 90 so that it can move East. I can't find useful functions for this purpose. I tried to use `Pen().degrees(90)` but that didn't work. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: do you have any code? it's hard to see what you're doing and explain how to fix it without any..

Comment: Yeah, some code from whatever you are trying would help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [turtle.setheading()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading)

```
>>> turtle.setheading(90)
>>> turtle.heading()
90.0
```

You can combine this with a simple dict to get exactly the result you are after.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried this, it gave me an error, but I believe that I can resolve that. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

turtle.right(90)
this will turn the turtle 90